# Unable to publish a desktop bridge app with CefSharp

Tags: c#, cefsharp, desktop-bridge

I also tried with the [CefSharp.MinimalExample](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample) (Wpf .NetCore):

1. The project runs fine, added a Windows Application Packaging Project to the solution
2. I referenced the sample project and the bridge app compiled an run successfully
3. Then when I tried to publish, it failed with the following error:

`Could not copy "C:\[user folder]\.nuget\packages\cefsharp.common\85.3.130\CefSharp\x64\CefSharp.dll" to "obj\x64\Release\PackageLayout\CefSharp.MinimalExample.Wpf.netcore\CefSharp.dll". Beginning retry 1 in 1000ms. The process cannot access the file 'obj\x64\Release\PackageLayout\CefSharp.MinimalExample.Wpf.netcore\CefSharp.dll' because it is being used by another process.`

The same error message with the following files as well: `CefSharp.Core.xml`, `CefSharp.Core.dll`, `CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.Core.dll` and `CefSharp.xml`.

As I see it cannot access the target file, but why? That should be created just now, when copied. Who started to use it?

And another error message:
`The primary reference "C:\[...]\CefSharp.MinimalExample-master\CefSharp.MinimalExample.Wpf\bin.netcore\x64\Release\netcoreapp3.0\win-x64\CefSharp.MinimalExample.Wpf.netcore.dll" could not be resolved because it has an indirect  dependency on the assembly "CefSharp.Wpf, Version=85.3.130.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=40c4b6fc221f4138" which was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework  ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1".`

But basically the project targets the `.NET Core 3.1`. For some reason it tries to use the wrong dll?